# How to print the value got from the db in the console?

Tags: android, mysql, eclipse, console

Hi I have developed an app which accesses the db and I want to know whether it is returning the values can this be done ie; can I print the values got from the db in the console of eclipse?

If so how to print it. Please help as I am new to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Log class.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Example:

```
Log.i("TAG", "something to display");
```

Comment: @user1929242 TAG is just a tag. It is a string that says something more about your message. I personally use here the name of the class which envelopes the code. You can put whatever string for tag. Just pick something meaningful.

Comment: Maybe you should read the link as well. There is more explanation. Its is better to use a tag for each component. I usually use: private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

Comment: what I want to do is that I am getting a return value from the php file which gets the data from the db I want to print this value..